# How to install classes in php?

Tags: php

How to install classes in php ?
On my server pdo is enabled.
pdo is a class.
In the same way I've found class.upload.php on internet which is used to upload and resize images.
Here is the link http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm from where I've downloaded the class.
I want to install class.upload.php

Do we have to include it in .php file or we need to install it on server and enable it ?

Comment: What you mean with install classes? If you mean OOP PHP then: You don't have to install that! and what should class.upload.php be? Should that be a normal php file ? You can write OOP PHP if you want you don't have to install something

Comment: Read everything on this site! If your done with everything and you have still a question create a new on! http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @DipaliPatil don't worry, I've just upvoted your question. Downvoting in SO is something happening frequently. One tip on asking a good question is try to make it as clear as possible and at least talk about what you've already tried (even some effort of searching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install classes to write OOP PHP!

You can just start writting!

Here are a few references that may help you:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php  //php.net reference
- http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bH5s3/0/1  //online learing!
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL75B9D91CD69ED950 //video tutorial

If your read all on php.net manual and you have still a question the you can create a new one!

Comment: shall I delete the question ? This question is getting negative votes...!!

Comment: @DipaliPatil i would overwrite it and ask about tips or oncrete questions!